# Convert table rows to column

Tags: sql-server

I have data like this:

**ColumnName** 
 

 
   row1
 
 
  row2
 
 
   row3
 
 
   ... 
 
 
   ...

I want the result like this

**row1        row2      row3     ...     ...**




true        false      true     ...     ...




false        false      true     ...     ...

Is this possible with PIVOT table? I have tried but unable to find any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are the 'true' & 'false' values coming from?

Comment: We need a little more information here. Is this a SQL table? Is it full of data? And like Tony said, where does the true/false values come from?

Comment: true false values will be generated with a sql function.  for example: dbo.isTrue(id1, id2)

Comment: yes this is sql table.  i.e select columnName from table

Comment: It would be useful if you would post the DDL for the table in question, some sample code and the expected output. Without that it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: Can you please suggest me that how can i change the rows to column. leave the true false.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use pivot. check out the link for a full explanation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Did you try Copy > Paste Special > Transpose option?

Comment: The question being asked is how to `PIVOT` a table in SQL, not Excel.

Answer (score -1):

Or try following :

=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3) in destination cell.

Comment: This has solved my issue.   DECLARE @listCol VARCHAR(2000) SELECT  @listCol = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT],[' + ltrim(CsProductName) FROM #tempBookingProducts
ORDER BY '],[' + ltrim(CsProductName) FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 2, '') + ']'  print @listCol

declare @query varchar(2000)
set @query = '
SELECT * 
  into #tempPivotTable
FROM
(
  SELECT BookingProductId, CsProductName
  FROM #tempBookingProducts
) AS t
PIVOT(SUM(BookingProductId) FOR CsProductName IN (' + @listCol + ')) AS p  select * from #tempPivotTable
drop table #tempPivotTable
'
execute(@query)

Comment: Can i use my own sql function here rather than using the aggregate funtion SUM(BookingProductId).

Comment: @Altaf Sami: You should edit your question to add additional information rather than place it in a comment under one of the (wrong) answers.